# OSGi Karaf not able to resolve dependecy

Tags: maven, osgi

This question is similar to one which are posted, but this is little different.

I have used Google guava and when maven install it gives the following error

```
Error executing command: Could not start bundle mvn:com.mycompany.webservices/dto/1.0.0 in feature(s) WebServicesGateway-0.0.0: Unresolved constraint in bundle 
com.mycompany.webservices.dto [224]: Unable to resolve 224.0: missing requirement [224.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.google.common.base)(version>=13.0.0)(!(version>=14.0.0
)))
```

when am marking the following in the pom.xml the maven install works fine.

```
<Import-Package>!com.google.common.base,
```

but this causes classDEFNotFound Exception during runtime.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Objects
```

I have tried with putting the version in the import to restrict the version number

```
<Import-Package>com.google.common.base;version="[13.0,13.0]",
```

I have tried to restrict it to 12.0, 11.0 and 10.0 but the error stays same.

I checked the maven .m2 repository and the jar file looks good.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Is the exported version in the guava-jar-file's manifest correct? Does Karaf list the guava-bundle as resolved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put the guava libraries to your osgi environment, which would export the packages your bundle needs. The current version (13) of the guava-jar comes osgi ready. Just drop that jar into karaf's deploy folder and you should be fine.

About your solution trials: You should not need to manually set the `Import-Package` property in your pom in most cases - the maven bundle plugin does resolve that for you. If an Import-Package like `com.google.guava` appears in your bundle's manifest, that means you really use that package in your bundle - so manually excluding it will not solve the problem. Actually OSGi tries to protect you from the `ClassNotFoundException` by requiring the imports to be resolved before it starts the bundle, you have exploited that protection mechanism by setting the import-package property.

Comment: Thank you benjamin, Actually it defied my logic if the jar is in .m2 why should it not be visible. Solution given by you works perfect. I have to deploy guava a bundle to use it.In our project we dont use deploy folder thus added the same to the features as below                                                      <features name="mycompany :: WebServices: features">

    <feature name="WebServices">
 <bundle>mvn:com.google.guava/guava/13.0</bundle>                ----- or we can use it as below to bundle deployment----   osgi:install mvn:com.google.guava/guava/13.0 on the karaf console.

Comment: Being available in m2 doesn't mean it will be resolved by Karaf. If it's a dependency for your application you have to provide it to Karaf. Karaf will not install Transitive dependencies automatically. For this feature you would need to install your Application through OBR. For your installment I recommend using a features file this way it's easy for you to collect all dependencies and install them all at once.

Comment: Good point Achim, an OBR is definitely practical for resolving dependencies, provided you have set it up. Although in case of the google guava libraries there are no further dependencies.